# lwc-jest install throwing audit errors

Tags: unit-test, lightning-web-components

After installing lwc-jest using npm the audit report is quite large. Does anyone know how the report items can be fixed?

Comment: You can run `npm audit fix`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that and let you know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all of the npm audit items are resolved by upgraded Jest from 23 to 24. Since this upgrade contains braking changes, `@saleforce/lwc-jest` won't upgrade Jest until the next Salesforce major release.

Comment: Thanks Trevor - I'm having some trouble upgrading npm at the moment since everything is owned by root and for some reason I don't have write access to the directories.